# Error for knn: no missing values are allowed - I don't have any missing values in the data

Tags: r, knn

I am working on a data mining project (as a total coding outsider) and am trying to run a K-Nearest Neighbor analysis. However, I keep getting the "no missing values are allowed" error. My data does not have missing values so something must be wrong with my code. Can anyone help?

```
AirbnbNYCApril = read.delim(file=file.choose(),
                            header = T,
                            sep = ",",
                            stringsAsFactors = F)
> str(AirbnbNYCApril)
AirbnbNYCApril = na.omit(AirbnbNYCApril)
set.seed(1)
n = nrow(AirbnbNYCApril)

Train_indices = 1:round(0.75*n)
Test_indices = (round(0.75*n)+1):n
AirbnbNYCApril_shuffle = AirbnbNYCApril[sample(n),]
AirbnbNYCApril_Train = AirbnbNYCApril_shuffle[Train_indices,]

AirbnbNYCApril_Test = AirbnbNYCApril_shuffle[Test_indices,]
Train_labels = AirbnbNYCApril_Train$neighborhood
Test_labels = AirbnbNYCApril_Test$neighborhood
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$neighborhood = NULL
AirbnbNYCApril_Test$neighborhood = NULL
min_reviews = min(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$reviews)
max_reviews = max(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$reviews)
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$reviews = (AirbnbNYCApril_Train$reviews - min_reviews)/(max_reviews - min_reviews)
AirbnbNYCApril_Test$reviews = (AirbnbNYCApril_Test$reviews - min_reviews)/(max_reviews - min_reviews)
min_accommodates = min(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$accommodates)
max_accommodates = max(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$accommodates)
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$accommodates = (AirbnbNYCApril_Train$accommodates - min_accommodates)/(max_accommodates - min_accommodates)
min_price = min(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$price)
max_price = max(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$price)
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$price = (AirbnbNYCApril_Train$price - min_price)/(max_price - min_price)
AirbnbNYCApril_Test$price = (AirbnbNYCApril_Test$price - min_price)/(max_price - min_price)
min_lat = min(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$latitude)
max_lat = max(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$latitutde)
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$latitude = (AirbnbNYCApril_Train$latitude - min_lat)/(max_lat - min_lat)
AirbnbNYCApril_Test$latitude = (AirbnbNYCApril_Test$latitude - min_lat)/(max_lat - min_lat)
min_lon = min(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$longitude)
max_lon = max(AirbnbNYCApril_Train$longitude)
AirbnbNYCApril_Train$longitude = (AirbnbNYCApril_Train$longitude - min_lon)/(max_lon - min_lon)
AirbnbNYCApril_Test$longitude = (AirbnbNYCApril_Test$longitude - min_lon)/(max_lon - min_lon)


neighborhood_prediction = knn(train = AirbnbNYCApril_Train[,-1], test = AirbnbNYCApril_Test[,-1], cl = Train_labels, k=5)

confusion_matrix = table(Test_labels, neighborhood_prediction)

print(confusion_matrix)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data, ideally using `dput`?

Comment: Hi!!! Thanks for reaching out! I had someone contact me directly and there was a mystery column "X" full of NA (therefore deleting my whole dataset with the na.omit() )that shows up in R but not in the original dataset.  This bit of code is all fixed. 

But stay tuned for more questions, haha. The project isn't finished yet!

Comment: this mysterious column is often the index column which is prone to import errors.